# deduplicate javascript code for tokenInput

Tags: javascript, django, code-duplication, jquery-tokeninput

There are many textboxes (Django CharField) for which I am using tokenInput as the JS plugin for autocomplete feature. To intialize each of them, I need to set prepopulate with different tag values. I want to avoid following code duplication as shown below.

```
$("#id_tags_1").tokenInput("/xyz/tag_search/", {
    theme: "facebook",
    onAdd: function(item){
        tag_ids.push(item.id);
        $("#id_tag_domain").val(tag_ids.join(','));
    },
    onDelete: function(item){
        tag_ids = _.without(tag_ids, item.id);
        $("#id_tag_domain").val(tag_ids.join(','));
    },
    preventDuplicates: true,
    tokenLimit: 3,
    prePopulate: tags_val[0],
});
$("#id_tags_2").tokenInput("/xyz/tag_search/", {
    theme: "facebook",
    onAdd: function(item){
        tag_ids.push(item.id);
        $("#id_tag_domain").val(tag_ids.join(','));
    },
    onDelete: function(item){
        tag_ids = _.without(tag_ids, item.id);
        $("#id_tag_domain").val(tag_ids.join(','));
    },
    preventDuplicates: true,
    tokenLimit: 3,
    prePopulate: tags_val[1],
});
```

I came across another SO post where regular expression like this `[^id_tags_]` was suggested but I don't know how to select each tag value corresponding to different tags. I think part of the problem is that I don't know how to access the tag id else I could have split it and extracted the number. If there is any other elegant solution, please do suggest.

Comment: `$("#id_tags_1, #id_tags_2, ...").tokenInput(...)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, you can select them with `$("[id^=id_tags_]")` (an [attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)). In the callbacks, if the plug-in is like standard plugins, `this` will refer to the element on which the original event causing the callback to occur was raised. So (again, *if* that plugin behaves in the normal way), within the callbacks, `this.id` should be the `id` of the element on which the event occured. But I don't know that plugin, sometimes plugins pass that information in a different way.

If that plugin *doesn't* provide access to the element on which the originating event occurred, you can still de-duplicate the code by using `each` and using the closure created by the `each` iterator function to remember the `id`:

```
$("[id^=id_tags_]").each(function() {
    // Get the index from the element `id`.
    // Note: If your elements are always in *document* order, instead
    // of this next line, you could just accept `index` as an argument,
    // it'll be `0` for the first matching element, `1` for the next,
    // etc. But I'm not assuming the elements are in document order, so
    // I'm deriving the index from the `id`.
    var index = parseInt(this.id.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10) - 1;

    $(this).tokenInput("/xyz/tag_search/", {
        theme: "facebook",
        onAdd: function(item){
            tag_ids.push(item.id);
            $("#id_tag_domain").val(tag_ids.join(','));
        },
        onDelete: function(item){
            tag_ids = _.without(tag_ids, item.id);
            $("#id_tag_domain").val(tag_ids.join(','));
        },
        preventDuplicates: true,
        tokenLimit: 3,
        prePopulate: tags_val[index],   // <=== Use `index` here (I assume this is the place)
    });
});
```

In that, we create new `tagInput` callbacks for each element in the `each` iterator function, and those are closures over the call to the iterator function, and so they have access to the `id` local variable (which will be specific to each call, and therefore to each element). If the term "closure" seems a bit alien, don't worry, [closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).

Comment: prePopulate: tags_val[parseInt(id.replace( /^\D+/g, '')) - 1],

Comment: @Kaiser: LOL, I just realized the OP was using the a 0-based index based on the `id` and edited...and with very similar code. :-)